# React onClick and preventDefault() not working

Tags: javascript, reactjs, react-redux

I've also tried all of the above using jQuery in my index.html, but nothing seems to work. What should I do here and what I'm doing wrong? I've checked event.type and it's click so I guess I should be able to avoid redirect somehow?

My component Component class:

```
class ActualNews extends Component{

    componentWillMount() {       
        this.props.fetchNews();
    }

    handleClick = (event) => {      
      this.props.loadNews('some_data');
      //event.preventDefault();
      //event.stopPropagation();
      //event.nativeEvent.stopImmediatePropagation();      
    }

    render(){
      const { list, loading, error } = this.props.dataList;

      if (loading || error){
        return 'loading ...';
      }else{      
        const categories = categories_list.map((c,ix) => {
          if (active_tab === 'actual_tab_'+c['slug'] )
            return (<li className="active" data-tab={'actual_tab_'+c['slug']}><a key={'actual_cat_'+c['slug']}  onClick={this.handleClick} data-slug={c['slug']} >{c['title']}</a></li>);
          else
            return (<li data-tab={'actual_tab_'+c['slug']}><a onClick={this.handleClick} data-slug={c['slug']} >{c['title']}</a></li>);            

      }

    }
}

const mapStateToProps = (state, ownProps) => {  
  return { 
      dataList: state.news.actual_section,
      posts: state.news.actual_posts
  };
}

const mapDispatchToProps = (dispatch) => {

  return {
    fetchNews: () => {
      dispatch(fetchActualNews('main')).then((response) => {
            !response.error ? dispatch(fetchActualNewsSuccess(response.payload.data)) : dispatch(fetchActualNewsFailure(response.payload.data));
          });
    },
    loadNews: (slug) => {
      dispatch(fetchActualPosts(slug)).payload.then((response) => {           
            !response.error ? dispatch(fetchActualPostsSuccess(response.data, slug)) : dispatch(fetchActualPostsFailure(response.data, slug));
        });      
    }  
  }
}
export default connect(mapStateToProps, mapDispatchToProps)(ActualNews);
```

when i click some tab menu reload tab. browser keeps scrolling...... i think when changed *this.props* reloading.

Excuse me, I'm a rookie when it comes to React.

Thank you!

Comment: Hi Botir, just to clarify- is your problem that the function is firing without being clicked?

Comment: what are you trying to prevent with `onClick` of an `li`?

Comment: onClick is on an "a" anchor

Comment: onClick is on an "a" anchor